# How I can made my website to be scaled on any device's screen

Tags: html

I tried the html meta tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

But it didn't work.
Please any tell me the answer
How I can made my website responsive

Comment: Can you post more of the code ?

Comment: you can use `display:flex`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make your website responsive you can do it the hard way manually by setting the width of any page-width element to 100%, such as the main `<div>` and then avoid appearance of any horizontal scroll bar. Or simply by using a responsive library such as Bootstrap 4.0.

To use bootstrap library put the following line in the `<head>` section:

```
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

And then in the body put your pages inside:

```html
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <!-- Your Page HTML Here -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

For more information and to learn Bootstrap 4 and understand how it works, please refer their official website:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/

You'll find other responsive components such as: menus, tabs, buttons, form controls, and many more things. Also you'll learn how to hide and show elements based on the screen width for major screen widths and also popups "called modals" and other comprehensive elements to use in your website to stay responsive.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=yes">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with more than a way but in case you are using HTML and CSS only you can do it using the CSS media query.
You can learn more about it from here: [Responsive Web Design - Media Queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use the media query in CSS to do so.

Like so:

```
@media only screen and (min-width:360px){

}
```

Here is a YouTube video on Responsive Web design that is really easy to follow: [Responsive Web Design by mmtuts](https://youtu.be/ZYV6dYtz4HA)